# Keycodes of function keys with F-lock off?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Many recent keyboard from Microsoft and Logitech have a so-called F-Lock key, which toggles the function keys F1 to F12 between their traditional keycodes and new meanings that are printed onto the keys: F1=Help F2=Undo F3=Redo F4=Open ... . (See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Lock.)

This means that long-established shortcuts such as Alt+F4 no longer work if the F-lock is off, and googling shows that quite a few people are unhappy about this.

So I'm wondering, what virtual key (VK) codes do the function keys send when F-lock is off?  VK_F13 to VK_F24 perhaps? Or do they not trigger standard keyboard events at all?

(I haven't got such a keyboard to try and find out myself, and didn't manage to dig up anything on MSDN about this.)

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629144518/http://jtsang.mvps.org/flock.html) says you can't detect F-lock programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to find this out so that I could make an application continue to work with F-Lock off and couldn't find a list so thought I'd post what I found. Rather than any new unique key-codes when F-Lock is off the following conventional key combinations are sent:

<kbd>F1</kbd> = <kbd>F1</kbd> (Help)

<kbd>F2</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (Undo)

<kbd>F3</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (Redo)

<kbd>F4</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (New)

<kbd>F5</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Open)

<kbd>F6</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (Close)

<kbd>F7</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Reply)

<kbd>F8</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Fwd)

<kbd>F9</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Send)

<kbd>F10</kbd> = <kbd>F7</kbd> (Spell)

<kbd>F11</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Save)

<kbd>F12</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Print)